# Ember data sideloaded mockjax call

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, mockjax

I try to model an ajax call via mockjax for ember data.

*my models:*

```
App.Service = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  service_prices: DS.hasMany('servicePrice')
});

App.ServicePrice = DS.Model.extend({
  unit_price: DS.attr('number'),
  qty_unit: DS.belongsTo('qtyUnit'),
  service: DS.belongsTo('service')
});


App.QtyUnit = DS.Model.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
  name: DS.attr('string'),

});

App.Order = DS.Model.extend({
  service: DS.belongsTo('service'),
  qty_unit:DS.belongsTo('qtyUnit'),
});
```

I try to load an `order` record via `mockjax`. (Push the button.) According to the console after the call

```
MOCK GET: /orders/1 
Object {url: "/orders/1", type: "GET", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true…}
```

Ember data tries a 2nd call

```
GET http://run.jsbin.com/services/%3CApp.Service:ember518:1%3E 404 (Not Found)
```

First of all i dont understend why is the 2nd call? Service is sideloaded in my order JSON

```
var order = {
  "order" : {"id":1,"service":1,"qty_unit":4},
  "service":[{"id":1,"name":"ENG-GER","service_prices":[1,2]}],
  "servicePrices":[
    {"id":1,"qty_unit":4,"unit_price":3},
    {"id":2,"qty_unit":5,"unit_price":4}
  ],
  "qtyUnits":[
    {"id":4,"name":"character"},
    {"id":5,"name":"word"},
    {"id":6,"name":"sentence"}   
  ]
};
```

And why tries ember-data call the record `App.Service:ember518:1` instead of its id "1"?

### Here is the JsBin

http://jsbin.com/finahuna/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was your setQtyUnits method. You were passing service model rather than just id as expected by your mock endpoint. ember518 is the ember generated name of service model instance in this case which was getting passed rather than id. Modified method is -

```
setQtyUnits:function(){

        var service_id = this.get('model.order.service.id');
        if (service_id !== null)
        {
          var self = this;
          //find returns a promise
          this.store.find('service',service_id).then(function(service){
            //on success
            var servicePrices = service.get('service_prices');
            var qtyUnits = servicePrices.mapBy('qty_unit');
            console.log(qtyUnits);
            self.set('qtyUnits', qtyUnits);
          });
        } else {
          this.set('qtyUnits', null);  
        }

  }.observes('model.order.service')
```

Here is the modified bin - http://jsbin.com/finahuna/4/edit